# SSL certification is missing

Tags: svn, ssl

I'm trying to setup an SSL SVN. I got a [tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51753), but when I'm trying to run the following command `apache2-ssl-certificate` I'm getting a `command not found` error message. My question is how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you've found is unfortunately very old. To generate a SSL cert run the following:

```
mkdir -p /etc/apache2/ssl
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
ln -sf /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem /etc/apache2/ssl/`/usr/bin/openssl x509 -noout -hash < /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem`.0
chmod 600 /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
```

This will create a SSL cert that expires in 365 days. To adjust the lifetime just change the `-days 365` argument.
Make sure that `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` contains something like:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Assuming you still enabled SSL (`sudo a2enmod ssl`) you need to create a new virtual host. For example create a file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/svn`, containing among others:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<virtualhost *:443>
        ...
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
        ...
</virtualhost>
```

and enable this site with `sudo a2ensite svn`. So you have a site that listens for SSL connection. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [bug #77675](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/77675). [A solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/77675/comments/60) is mentioned in the comments. I have not tried it myself so I don't know if it's correct. Anyway the solution should be to do the following:

```
apt-get install apache2
a2enmod ssl
a2ensite default-ssl
make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: it's not working.